comprasion of data (ranks) to a certain data sample
Excuse me for mistakes, non-native here.
I'll describe my uni research and the problem i have troubles solving.
I study perception of composition in paintings, for this i have two independent groups: artists and non-artists. I use method of paired comprasion, thus the participants are given a certain number of pairs cosisting of 2 paintings each, each participant should choose what composition they evaluate as more balanced in each pair. I calculate winrate of every painting, meaning it's score for every participant. The scores of paintings for every participant are transormed into ranks (1 - the most balanced composition, ..., 10 - the most disbalanced). I need to compare ranks for 2 groups (artists and non-artists) with the 'right answers' on composition type (the 10 paintings i give to the participants are of two types, 5 unbalanced and 5 balanced, taken from the source of expertise in art). The question is how to extract meaningful results ouf of it in a correct statistical way. As it seems, group of artists are better (obviously) at seeing the right type of composition.
the question is: How do i find a correlation of each group to the 'oficial' types of compositions?
There were two ideas on my side, but i am not really sure.

Coefficient of Correlation by Guilford, though yet i could not find the detailed information on these method and calculations.
More complex scheme, idk if it makes sense. I thought about turning 'official' composition types into ranks (ranks in this case the same or equel: for ten paintings it is 8,8,8,8,8,3,3,3,3,3. looks pretty stupid). After this, the official ranks could be compared to the first group and then to the second. We end up with two coefficients of correlation to the 'ideal' ranks sample. Those coefficients could be analyzed through The Fisher Z transformation.

Also, the ranks for two groups contain a lot of equal ranks as well, which is important for choosing right statistical method.
And btw do i need to find 'mean' ranks for each group or smt like that?
*And is there a way to also investigate the dispersion of answers for both groups? (i expect that the artists would more often give each painting the same rank, than non-artists)
Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Update: day of researching and it seems like i find a way to analyse the data - anova Friedman's test for each group. The results look nice. im still open for discussion though!  :)

If you want to compare ranks, then why do you want to look at correlations at all?

I think i just haven't came across methods for comprasion? I don't know how to do it correctly and google does not help apparently. and my knowledge of statistics is quite bad to be honest. If you have any suggestions (what to look for) it would be a great help
